# Python: Converting Standard Time to Military time

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that prompts a user to enter time in a 12-hour format and converts it to a 24-hour format. Converting a 12-hour time to 24-hour time requires adding 12 hours to any time between 1:00PM-11:59PM and subtracting 12 hours from any time between 12:00AM-12:59AM. 24-hour time uses leading zeros for hours so that there are always 4 digits.

This is currently in one my labs that I am trying to finish up for the semester and I do not know how to finish it.

Comment: could you give example of the data that you have? you do not have to reinvent the wheel, you just need to change the formating.

Comment: I have to input a time. For example, my input would be 4:21 PM and it would convert to 16:21 and 9:21 AM would convert to 09:21

Comment: What is the class of your time? How fo you input the time? Is it just a string??

Comment: You input the time as a string and are supposed split the string to find the results.

Comment: Does the string also contain the Date? or its just time?

Comment: The string just contains the time and whether it is AM or PM.

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_24hrs():
    txt = input('input the 12-hour format: ')
    tim = datetime.strptime(f'2021-12-09 {txt}', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
    print(datetime.strftime(tim, '%H:%M'))

convert_24hrs()
   # input the 12-hour format: 4:21 am
   # 04:21

convert_24hrs()
    # input the 12-hour format: 5:36 pm
    # 17:36
```

Comment: This code is entered wrong. Please correct to 
```tim = datetime.strptime(f'2021-12-09 {txt}', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
    print(datetime.strftime(tim, '%H:%M'))```

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone want to have the hour or minutes as an integers you can use this concept.

```
import datetime
    
YEAR        = datetime.date.today().year     # the current year
MONTH       = datetime.date.today().month    # the current month
DATE        = datetime.date.today().day      # the current day
HOUR        = datetime.datetime.now().hour   # the current hour
MINUTE      = datetime.datetime.now().minute # the current minute
SECONDS     = datetime.datetime.now().second #the current second
    
print(YEAR, MONTH, DATE, HOUR, MINUTE, SECONDS)
```

So with the above understanding you can get the difference in hours.
Let's reproduce onyambu example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_24hrs():
    txt = input('input the 12-hour format: ')
    tim = datetime.strptime(f'2021-12-09 {txt}', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
    print(f'{str(tim.hour)}:{str(tim.minute)}')

convert_24hrs()
    # input the 12-hour format: 5:36 pm
    # 17:36
```